# Flip Image continuously like tile in windows phone 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, tile

I have one image in Grid. I want to give *image* a continuous **flip** effect like tiles in home screen. Also on tap **tilt** effect. How can we achieve this? any good start?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://phone.codeplex.com is the official toolkit for Windows Phone apps, this kit includes new components, functionalities and more. Effects like `Effects – SlideInEffect, TiltEffect and TurnstileFeatherEffect` are available

Also you can use `HubTile` for flip effect for tile image in your application

Comment: I was asking about windows phone 8.1 store app. I knew toolkit but its only available for silverlight

Comment: Oh great, please check this post then http://stackoverflow.com/a/25245208/2526869

Answer (score 0):

You can try FlipView :

You can Change title effect by FlipView.SelectIndex